# Why do I get asked about privacy every time I reach Stack Overflow through a search?

Tags: support, cookies

Even after accepting the privacy settings, I get that annoying popup.  Is it me, my browser, or something to do with Stack Overflow?

Comment: Some adblocker- or privacy-type extension?  pihole or other privacy traffic blocker?  I don't get this with Google Chrome 64-bit for Windows 10/11.

Comment: IF it were something to do with Stack Overflow, you can bet that you won't be the one reporting it. The site is used by millions of people after all. It has happened that problems are isolated to a specific region due to failure to update a node in a CDN but even then you're hardly going to be the only one to notice it. Assume it's you unless you see proof otherwise.

Comment: Looks like the issue was with DuckDuckGo.  I added stackoverflow.com as an unprotected site within DDG.